# Trying to find GCD of 2 Gauss-integers with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is that if the two norms are equal there's going to be an endless loop. My prof assured me that the normal Euclidien algorithm would do fine, I have no idea what to do.

```
def norm(u):                #norm of complex number 
    return (u.real**2+u.imag**2)
def gcd(z,w):               #looking for 2 Gauss int's gcd
    d=z-w               #their difference
    counter=0               #I'd like to have at most 30 iterations
    while d!=0+0j and counter<=30 and norm(z)!=norm(w):
#if d=0 We're done, if the two norms are equal there's going to be an endless loop
        print (z, w, d) 
        if norm(z)>=norm(w):
            z=z-w
        else:
            w=w-z    
        counter=counter+1
        if norm(z)>norm(w):
            d=z-w
        else:
            d=w-z
    return (z,w)                #either of these is supposed to be the gcd
```